# Cordova dialog plugin not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I've been stuck on this issue for 10+ hours now and I'm having no luck in fixing it by myself. The problem is that I'm trying to use this dialog plugin on my Cordova app but its not working. I don't even think that the deviceready script is working.

Any questions feel free to ask

**www/index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content=".." />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <link href="css/layout-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <title>Plugins Not Working</title>

        <script src="cordova.js">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false)

            function onDeviceReady() {     
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Script has loaded',  // message
                    alertDismissed,       // callback
                    'Loaded',             // title
                    'Done'                // buttonName
                );
            };

            function alertDismissd() {
                // do something
            };

         </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^1.3.3" />` is in config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled windows 10 and reinstalled cordova as a whole. Now all plugins work :) sorry if this isnt the answer you wanted but it worked for me! Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Your code in `<script>` tag seems alright. If you have added the `dialogs` plugin using -

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
```

that should work fine.

And **don't** add `src="cordova.js"` for the script containing your code. Just do this -

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false)

function onDeviceReady() {     
navigator.notification.alert(
   'Script has loaded',  // message
    alertDismissed,       // callback
    'Loaded',             // title
    'Done'                // buttonName
    );
};

function alertDismissd() {
     // do something
};

</script>
```

If it still doesn't work, can you [inspect in Google Chrome](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/), see and list the error messages under `Console` tab? There might be some error before that `<script>` if that `onDeviceReady()` is not triggered.

**UPDATE** after seeing error messages from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTKz7.jpg) -

1. Remove `<script src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>` That's not required. Plugins are directly called from `js`.
2. `Cannot read property 'alert' of undefined` => the plugin is not properly installed. Install it first using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs` in cmd.
3. Remove `<script src="js/index.js"></script>`. As you are doing everything inside `<script>` tag, you don't need `index.js` or its `js` contents (has errors).

Comment: There are 3 errors. Ill send a picture just so I dont type anything wrong: http://imgur.com/a/nHz9w   This is the built version in the assets folder

Comment: Thanks, the first 'cordova is not defined error' has fixed but the other 2 are still there

Comment: ok so the 3rd error is now fixed but I reinstalled the dialog plugin and its still coming up with that error.

Comment: That should work as far as I know. can you **rebuild** the project and try again?

Comment: Ive tried. The only thing I can think of is installing an older version of dialogs?

Comment: No. don't go for older versions. `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.notification);
}` Can you see and tell what this logs in console?

Comment: it returns with undefined

Comment: This plugin provides access to some native dialog UI elements via a global `navigator.notification` object.

Although the object is attached to the global scoped `navigator`, it is not available until after the `deviceready` event. So your `deviceready` event is not caught properly.

Comment: thanks for the help. I'll hopefully figure it out soon. Have a good day :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148379/discussion-between-pro-cheats-and-william-sharp).